# Why does Bundler build a module Foo into lib/foo.rb?

Tags: ruby, module, rubygems, bundler, executable

I am working with bundler and reproducing the basic gem found on [rubygems.org](https://guides.rubygems.org/make-your-own-gem/), to gain a better grasp running `gems` as `executables`.  I am reproducing only the necessary code here for succinctness' sake.

`bundle gem foo` creates the necessary gem tree.  However in the skeleton of `lib/foo.rb`

```
module Foo
class Error < StandardError; end
...
end
```

In `irb`, when I run `ruby -Ilib ./bin/foo`, irb throws out an error: 
`/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in 'require': cannot load such file -- foo (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in 'require'
    from ./bin/foo:3:in`'`

**I DO get my desired result (matching the result [hola mundo](https://guides.rubygems.org/make-your-own-gem/) when I remove the `module Foo` and `class Error` in `foo.rb`.**

My **2 interconnected questions** are thus: 1 **Why is a module prebuilt by bundler into lib/foo.rb?**

and 2 **Why does the module break my executable?**

Comment: 1. Convention...

Comment: Fair enough...can you provide an answer to question 2 (which is more important, in a way - at least)